# Where to keep Aptana Studio 3 IDE unzipped folder?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, ide, aptana

[Aptana](http://aptana.com/) for linux comes as ready-to-launch zipped package. The
problem is that I don't know where I should put this unzipped folder.

I don't like it being in (polluting!) my home folder.

Where would you put this? Any suggestions? Where do you keep your Aptana's folder? Where would be the most elegant place? Is there special place to put such executables (like `C:/Program Files` on Windows)?

Comment: I keep that kind of stuff in my /opt directory.

Comment: @mja, if you could add this as answer so I can accept it would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep that kind of stuff in my /opt directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have it setup:
1. I have created /home/bin and put the execs there (added bin to my Path so i can open Aptana straight from the terminal) 
2. Created a "development" folder in the home folder (same level as Documents) and i have all my projects in that directory.

I am really not sure this is the right way since I am new to this too but this is what made sense to me.